# Lookup value based on group max value in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to first state that I am a beginner with DAX and this is one of my attempts (which seemed to be the closest to the solution I need). I come from a SQL heavy background so my "thinking" is somehow fixed in that way.

I have tried to solve this by implementing something that would match the following SQL logic:

```
CASE WHEN MAX(column) OVER (PARTITION BY group) = column2 THEN column3 ELSE "" END
```

However, this doesn't seem to work directly like in SQL, so I would like to ask for some help.

---

I have the current set of data, which is imported from a simple text file.

```
ID    GroupID    Amount
1     2          8502
2     2          8502
3     2          8502
4     2          8502
1     6          80
2     6          80
```

And I would like to find a way to get the following result:

```
ID    GroupID    Amount    LatestGroupAmount
1     2          8502
2     2          8502
3     2          8502
4     2          8502      8502
1     6          80
2     6          80        80
```

And then have a Total under LatestGroupAmount, totaling to 8582.

So far, I have created 2 new measures in my table, MaxID and MaxIDbyGroup.

> MaxID = MAX(data[ID])

and

> MaxIDbyGroup = CALCULATE([MaxID], ALLEXCEPT(data, data[GroupID]))

This gives me:

```
ID    GroupID    Amount    MaxID    MaxIDbyGroup
1     2          8502      1        4
2     2          8502      2        4
3     2          8502      3        4
4     2          8502      4        4
1     6          80        1        2
2     6          80        2        2
```

Now, I would like to create a new measure that just does a lookup of the Amount, based on the equality between ID and MaxIDbyGroup.

I have tried to create a new measure with the following definition:

> LatestGroupAmount = LOOKUPVALUE(data[Amount], data[GroupId], data[MaxIDbyGroup])

But this gives me the following output:

```
ID    GroupID    Amount    LatestGroupAmount
1     2          8502
2     2          8502
3     2          8502
4     2          8502      
1     6          80        8502
2     6          80        8502
```

---

**Edit:**

I have created another measure:

> MaxGrid = MAX(data[GroupID])

And I have tried using `CALCULATE` with the following definition for `LatestGroupAmount`:

> LatestGroupAmount =  CALCULATE(
> SUM( data[Amount] ),
> FILTER( data, data[ID] = data[MAXID_by_author]), FILTER(data, data[GroupID] = data[MaxGrid]) )

And it seems to show what I want, however, it filters the 6 rows I have to only 2 rows (although I think it does an aggregation).

```
ID    GroupID    Amount    LatestGroupAmount
4     2          8502      8502
2     6          80        80
```

The reason I say I think it's an aggregation, is because I add the `MaxID` to the widget, the output shows the correct number of rows. Essentially, the image below is the output that I want, except for the `MaxID` column.

[image]

If I remove the `MaxID` column, the widget automatically summarizes to two rows, but I want to show all of the 6 rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this measure to achieve your result:

```
LatestGroupAmount = 
VAR TT01 = ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(Data,Data[ID],Data[GroupID]),
    "MaxID",CALCULATE(MAX(Data[ID]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[GroupID]))
    )
RETURN  
    CALCULATE(MAX(Data[Amount]),
        FILTER(TT01,
        Data[ID] =[MaxID]))
```

Then define your visual table by putting [ID], [GroupID],[Amount] on rows, and above measure into values, Then:

[image: DFRE]

Please Make sure that For [ID] and [GroupID Columns], show items with no data is ticked or checked, like in the picture below.

[image: DFS]

Comment: That was it: "Show items with no data", that worked with the other approach at calculating the `LatestGroupAmount` which I already created.

Answer (score 0):

Your current definition for *LatestGroupAmount* is searching in the *GroupId* column, though I believe that should be the *ID* column, i.e.:

```
LOOKUPVALUE( data[Amount], data[ID], data[MaxIDbyGroup] )
```

In any case, this will fail since that column contains duplicate entries. As such, you should use something like:

```
LatestGroupAmount :=
CALCULATE(
    MAX( data[Amount] ),
    FILTER( data, data[Id] = data[MaxIDbyGroup] )
)
```

Comment: It worked, however it aggregated all of my rows to only 2 rows, grouped by GroupID I believe. I would like to not have them aggregated.

Comment: @Udar Sorry, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I have edited my question with an update.

Comment: You need to set the *Summarization* dropdown in the *Column tools* ribbon to 'Don't summarize' for the two fields *ID* and *GroupID*.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have done that, for all the columns I've selected. Even if I remove the other columns that I have in the widget and only leave these four, I still have only 2 rows. I created a screengrab and uploaded it here: https://imgur.com/a/6gfEMET . Also, I changed the `MAX()` to a `SUM()` in the calculation for `LatestGroupAmount` since I noticed the totals for 8502 and 80 does not add up, it just does the MAX.

Comment: The sigma symbol still shows next to the *GroupID* and *ID* columns in the Fields pane on the right of that screengrab, which means that they are still **not** set to 'Don't summarize'. You should be setting it within the *Column tools* ribbon, as I suggested. You might then need to remove them from the visual and then reinstate them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the `Column tools` ribbon, I have mistaken it with the "ribbon" for summarization on each column. I have done as you suggested, removed summarization for all columns and created a new visual widget and added the columns. The result, however, is still the same: https://imgur.com/a/ydpkw0Y

Comment: Why have you removed the summarization for *Amount*? That *should* be set to sum.

Comment: I added it back, but it doesn't seem to help in generating the 6 rows. Can we move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Did you remove that field from the visual and then add it back in?

Comment: Yes, I created a completely new visual and added the columns back. The solution was to check "Show items with no data" on the `ID` field. Otherwise, the logic for generating the result, was ok.